# Error in creating Excel through Android Application

Tags: android, excel, jxl

I am using the jxl package for creating a excel file and export it to SD card through my android application. I have added the jxl.jar to my referenced libraries in my application package in eclipse.

But still when I run the application, it is force closed and I get the below error in logcat

09-10 00:10:31.242: E/dalvikvm(321): Could not find class 'jxl.WorkbookSettings', referenced from method h.pkg.main.ExportActivity$2.onClick

Please see below my code for reference..

```
        export.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Fnamexls="Report-" + tname + ".xls";
            String Fnamehtml="Report-" + tname + ".htm";
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/TripManager");
            directory.mkdirs();

            if (fityp == 0){
                File file = new File(directory, Fnamexls); 

                WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

                wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

                WritableWorkbook workbook;
                try {
                    workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
                    workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
                    WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
                    createExcel(excelSheet);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (WriteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Am getting the class not found error when creating the WorkbookSettings obeject wbSettings in the above code. Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the project properties (right click the project -> `Properties`, assuming you are in Eclipse), go to `Java Build Path`, and to the `Order and Export` tab. Make sure that the checkbox next to `jxl.jar` *is* checked.